# 'MySQL server has gone away' in Laravel queue worker job

Tags: mysql, laravel, doctrine

A job on the queue is giving a timeout for a very simple select query.
The project is using Laravel 7.4 with Mysql 5.7 and Doctrine 2.10.1.

The error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

When retrying the job it fails again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Laravel and Doctrine, sometimes the queue workers lose their database connection.
`php artisan queue:restart` should fix the problem right away.